# slick slider not initializing in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code I have, any reason why this might be? It's just not initalising.

```
<div class="slider-banner slick-slider">
    <div class="slide1 slide slick-slide">
        ...
    </div> 
    <div class="slide2 slide slick-slide"></div> 
    ...

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/slick.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$('.slider-banner').slick({ 
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 600,
    mobileFirst: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,        
    onInit: function() {
        $('.slider-banner').addClass("loaded");
    },
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1280,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 5,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
        }
    }, {
        breakpoint: 1600,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 7,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: Are you using jQuery 2.x, which only supports IE 9+? Also JS fiddle would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

remove old jquery refrence add this

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```